# How can I store what video I am watching using Python in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, python

I am new to Ubuntu. I watch a lot of TV shows and sometimes lose track of what I am watching.

When I used Windows, I refered to the list that pops up on right-clicking the VLC icon to keep track of what I have seen. I can't seem to find something similar in Ubuntu. So I was thinking of storing the title and path of a video in a text file whenever I run a video.

Is it possible to do so, and how? I almost always use VLC for watching a video.

Thanks!

Comment: In general - yes that is possible with python, but it's somehow related with work for that particular script.I wrote myself a python script which logs the frontmost window (appm title, pid), but thats another target. I can imagine it would be easier in your case to just refer to Zeitgeist and it's journal to keep track if you watched something already or not if thats an option for you (i am not 100% sure if VLC events are reported to zeitgeist at all)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to extract the *local* videos you're watching, not things like Youtube?

In that case, you might want to have a look at the Gnome Activity Journal. It tells you what you've watched and when you did it, by time and date. This is accomplished using Zeitgeist, for which there is a library for Python if you want to do specific things with that data. This is also the same system that's used to display what files you've used in Unity Dash. If you're not aware of it, there is a special tab in the dash that shows you the last files you've used and you can search. I did that only a few hours ago, when I wanted to see which episode of the Family Guy I watched last. So I just did Super+F and entered "family". If you want to remove entries from the log, you need Gnome Activity Journal, or you make something yourself, of course.

Zeitgeist also stores which apps you've used to open these files, so you could for instance choose to display which files you've ever opened with VLC on Thursday afternoons during the last three months.

Zeitgeist is a really nice tool, that's severely under utilized. More apps, scripts and high-level tools, are very welcome. If you make something cool, do share! :)

EDIT: I found a link that I think you might be interested in. It's a little old, but Zeitgeist shouldn't have changed much since then. http://bloc.eurion.net/archives/2012/zeitgeist-python-api-tutorial/